# How can define an enum for Shape with defined and custom shapes

Tags: swift, swiftui

If we look to **clipShape** modifier `.clipShape(shape: Shape)` it is a function that takes a shape and do it works! I have no problem to adapt this kind input value of usage in my codes, the thing that I am looking is an enum type parameter, for example I want that I be able use `ShapeType.circle` for referencing to **Circle()** or `ShapeType.rectangle` for **Rectangle()** and also having a case for custom shape as well.
What I tried so for is like this:

```
extension View {
    
    // Issue is here!!! Reference to generic type 'ShapeType' requires arguments in <...>

    func backShape(shape: ShapeType) -> some View {

    return self
            .background(shape.fill(Color.red))
    }
}


enum ShapeType<ShapeContent: Shape> {
    case circle
    case rectangle
    case custom(shape: ShapeContent)
}
```

having cases of circle or rectangle makes no issue, but having a case for custom shape make issue because I need to access the Shape protocol as ShapeContent. And that make issue for use case in function parameter! Xcode asking for Shape type or kind before get decided from user or developer, I fully understand the issue and I know why that happens, but I cannot help myself to use my approach for making my goal of enum shape for function parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums do not work for this in Swift. That is why [SE-0299](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0299-extend-generic-static-member-lookup.md) came about—to emulate what code would look like if enums could do what you want.

```swift
func backShape<Shape: SwiftUI.Shape>(_ shape: Shape) -> some View {
  background(shape.fill(Color.red))
}
```

```swift
extension Shape where Self == Circle {
  static var circle: Self { .init() }
}

extension Shape where Self == Rectangle {
  static var rectangle: Self { .init() }
}
```

```swift
backShape(.circle)
backShape(.rectangle)
backShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: 10))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Jessy, as I mentioned I have no issue to import Shape content as they are like Circle or Rec or custom Shape, no need to those extension you made if we are not using enum, I mean if we cannot use enum, then i can ask for shape in function parameter from developer, that could be a Circle or a custom one.

Comment: Also I liked your Shape definition in function. Nice!